# ggplot2 functions not inheriting?

Tags: r, ggplot2

After updating to ggplot2 2.0 some of my visualisation code broke and in trying to figure out why, this behaviour concerned me. Running an internal ggplot2 function such as geom_point after the base call of ggplot(), it appears as if geom_point doesn't inherit the data structures from the original ggplot() call.

Example:

```
test <- data.frame(a = 1:100, b = 801:900)
ggplot(test, aes(x=a, y=b)) + geom_point()
Error: geom_point requires the following missing aesthetics: x, y
```

Is this explicit defining of aesthetics in each internal ggplot2 call now the default behaviour?

session info:

```
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.2 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
 [1] grid      stats4    parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
 [9] methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] IlluminaHumanMethylation450kanno.ilmn12.hg19_0.2.1
 [2] biomaRt_2.26.1                                    
 [3] GenomicFeatures_1.22.7                            
 [4] AnnotationDbi_1.32.3                              
 [5] biovizBase_1.18.0                                 
 [6] ggbio_1.18.1                                      
 [7] cowplot_0.6.0                                     
 [8] gridExtra_2.0.0                                   
 [9] doParallel_1.0.10                                 
[10] IlluminaHumanMethylation450kmanifest_0.4.0        
[11] scales_0.3.0                                      
[12] reshape2_1.4.1                                    
[13] ggplot2_2.0.0                                     
[14] limma_3.26.4                                      
[15] lumi_2.22.0                                       
[16] minfi_1.16.0                                      
[17] bumphunter_1.10.0                                 
[18] locfit_1.5-9.1                                    
[19] iterators_1.0.8                                   
[20] foreach_1.4.3                                     
[21] Biostrings_2.38.3                                 
[22] XVector_0.10.0                                    
[23] SummarizedExperiment_1.0.2                        
[24] GenomicRanges_1.22.3                              
[25] GenomeInfoDb_1.6.1                                
[26] IRanges_2.4.6                                     
[27] S4Vectors_0.8.7                                   
[28] lattice_0.20-33                                   
[29] Biobase_2.30.0                                    
[30] BiocGenerics_0.16.1                               

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] nlme_3.1-122             bitops_1.0-6             matrixStats_0.50.1      
 [4] RColorBrewer_1.1-2       tools_3.2.3              doRNG_1.6               
 [7] nor1mix_1.2-1            affyio_1.40.0            rpart_4.1-10            
[10] KernSmooth_2.23-15       Hmisc_3.17-1             DBI_0.3.1               
[13] mgcv_1.8-10              colorspace_1.2-6         nnet_7.3-11             
[16] methylumi_2.16.0         GGally_1.0.0             base64_1.1              
[19] preprocessCore_1.32.0    graph_1.48.0             pkgmaker_0.22           
[22] labeling_0.3             rtracklayer_1.30.1       genefilter_1.52.0       
[25] quadprog_1.5-5           affy_1.48.0              RBGL_1.46.0             
[28] stringr_1.0.0            digest_0.6.8             Rsamtools_1.22.0        
[31] foreign_0.8-66           illuminaio_0.12.0        siggenes_1.44.0         
[34] GEOquery_2.36.0          dichromat_2.0-0          BSgenome_1.38.0         
[37] RSQLite_1.0.0            BiocInstaller_1.20.1     mclust_5.1              
[40] BiocParallel_1.4.3       acepack_1.3-3.3          VariantAnnotation_1.16.4
[43] RCurl_1.95-4.7           magrittr_1.5             Formula_1.2-1           
[46] futile.logger_1.4.1      Matrix_1.2-3             Rcpp_0.12.2             
[49] munsell_0.4.2            stringi_1.0-1            nleqslv_2.9.1           
[52] MASS_7.3-45              zlibbioc_1.16.0          plyr_1.8.3              
[55] splines_3.2.3            multtest_2.26.0          annotate_1.48.0         
[58] beanplot_1.2             igraph_1.0.1             rngtools_1.2.4          
[61] corpcor_1.6.8            codetools_0.2-14         mixOmics_5.2.0          
[64] futile.options_1.0.0     XML_3.98-1.3             latticeExtra_0.6-26     
[67] lambda.r_1.1.7           gtable_0.1.2             reshape_0.8.5           
[70] xtable_1.8-0             survival_2.38-3          OrganismDbi_1.12.1      
[73] GenomicAlignments_1.6.3  registry_0.3             ellipse_0.3-8           
[76] cluster_2.0.3            rgl_0.95.1441
```

Comment: I suspect one of the many packages you have attached hasn't been updated to play well with ggplot2 2.0 and masks `+.gg`.

Comment: I was just about to edit... After starting a new session from scratch, it appears you're right, one of the other packages has masked something essential by the looks of things.

Comment: ggbio seems a likely candidate.

Comment: It is usually a good idea to restart R after updating/installing packages.